# Report design not valid Error Message

Tags: jasper-reports

I have edit query from old template by replace new query sql.

Error message comes as :

```
Compiling to file... C:\ECLIPSE\workspace\EIS-HR\Web-inf\hradmin\HR_EIS1.jasper
Active top component: null C:\ECLIPSE\workspace\EIS-HR\Web-inf\hradmin\HR_EIS1.jrxml
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid :       
1. Field not found : DM_DEPT_DESC      2. Field not found : SM_GENDER
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.verifyDesign(JRAbstractCompiler.java:271) 
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:153) 
at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:512) 
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572) 
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997) 
Compilation running time: 231
```

Field not found, where is wrong to my xml file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your report template is looking for two fields (DM_DEPT_DESC and SM_GENDER) that are not found in your query results.